# How I can get output from 1st frame textfield input text to 2nd frame textArea

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Here is my 1st frame - I want went I input text in textfield example name then click button report will display output to 2nd frame using textArea... please help me

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;


public class Order extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JPanel pInfo,pN, pIC, pDate,Blank,pBlank, button, pTotal;

    private JLabel nameL,icL,DateL;

    private JTextField nameTF, icTF;

    private JFormattedTextField DateTF;

    private JButton calB,clearB,exitB,reportB;


    public Order()
    {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.gray);


          pInfo             = new JPanel();     

          pN                = new JPanel();
          pIC               = new JPanel();
          pDate             = new JPanel();


            nameTF      = new JTextField(30);
            icTF        = new JTextField(30);    
            DateTF      = new JFormattedTextField(
                                   java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            DateTF.setEditable (false);
            DateTF.addActionListener(this);


        nameL      = new JLabel(" NAME : ",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        icL        = new JLabel(" IC   :   ",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        DateL      = new JLabel(" DATE :",SwingConstants.RIGHT);


        pInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,2,5,5));

        pInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder
        (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),"ORDER"));


        pN.add(nameL); 
        pN.add(nameTF);

        pIC.add(icL); 
        pIC.add(icTF);

        pDate.add(DateL);
        pDate.add(DateTF);


      pInfo.add(pN);
        pInfo.add(pIC);
        pInfo.add(pDate);


        pInfo.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        pN.setBackground(Color.gray);    
        pIC.setBackground(Color.gray);
        pDate.setBackground(Color.gray);

        nameL.setForeground(Color.black); 
        icL.setForeground(Color.black); 
        DateL.setForeground(Color.black); 

        nameTF.setBackground(Color.pink);
        icTF.setBackground(Color.pink);
        DateTF.setBackground(Color.pink);


          contentPane.add(pInfo,BorderLayout.CENTER);



        Blank   = new JPanel();
        pBlank  = new JPanel();
        button  = new JPanel();

        calB = new JButton("CALCULATE");
        calB.setToolTipText("Click to calculate");

        clearB  = new JButton("RESET");
        clearB.setToolTipText("Click to clear");

            reportB = new JButton ("REPORT");
            reportB.setToolTipText ("Click to print");

        exitB   = new JButton("EXIT");
        exitB.setToolTipText("Click to exit");

        Blank.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        Blank.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder
        (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),""));

            button.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));

            button.add(calB,BorderLayout.WEST);
            button.add(clearB,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            button.add(reportB,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            button.add(exitB,BorderLayout.EAST);

            Blank.add(pBlank); 
            Blank.add(button);   

      contentPane.add(Blank,BorderLayout.SOUTH);    


        Blank.setBackground(Color.gray);
        pBlank.setBackground(Color.gray);

        calB.setForeground(Color.black);
        clearB.setForeground(Color.black);
        reportB.setForeground(Color.black);
        exitB.setForeground(Color.black);
        calB.setBackground(Color.pink);
        clearB.setBackground(Color.pink);
        reportB.setBackground(Color.pink);        
        exitB.setBackground(Color.pink);          


            calB.addActionListener(this);
            clearB.addActionListener(this);
            reportB.addActionListener(this);
            exitB.addActionListener(this);

        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p)
        {

        if (p.getSource() == calB)
        {
        }   

    else if (p.getSource() == clearB)
    {
    }

    else if (p.getSource () == reportB)
    {

   }

    else if (p.getSource() == exitB)
        {
        }
}

    public static void main (String [] args)
        {

        Order frame = new Order();
        frame.setTitle("Order");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//center the frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add some reference to the first frame in the second or pass the value you're interested in to the second frame before you display it.

As for the code example you requested:

```
public class SecondFrame extends JFrame {
    private JFrame firstFrame;

    public SecondFrame(JFrame firstFrame) {
        this.firstFrame = firstFrame;
    }
}
```

Now you can obtain everything there is to obtained from the firstFrame through the internal reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one `String` to pass, add it to the constructor of your second `JFrame`:

```
public class SecondFrame extends JFrame {
    public SecondFrame(String someValueFromFirstFrame) {
        someTextField.setText(someValueFromFirstFrame);
    }
}
```

and pass it when creating the second `JFrame`:

```
SecondFrame secondFrame = new SecondFrame(firstTextField.getText());
```

---

If there is more than one attribute to pass, consider putting them together in another class and pass the instance of this class. This saves you from changing the constructor every time you need to pass an additional variable.